# Can't install php7.4 on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: php

I'm having trouble installing php7.4 on ubuntu 20 with the following command

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4
```

On my ubuntu partition it works just fine, but when trying to install it on WSL and typing `php -v` I get that the current version is PHP 7.3.32 (cli)

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   Ubuntu Core 20 doesn't use `apt` commands; that's used only by *year.month* format releases; as the *year* format products are *snap* only.

Comment: Oh my bad then, I was under the impression that ubuntu 20 gets installed while using wsl

Comment: If you have multiple versions of PHP installed, you’ll need to set the version you want to use [via `update-alternatives`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373766/1222991) 

Comment: What guiverc above means is that you're likely using Ubuntu 20.04 because "Ubuntu Core 20" is a different product. When asking you should be precise.

Comment: @matigo I tried running `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and was presented with the php8.0 and php7.4 options (both on /usr/bin) but even after manually changing them, when I run `php -v` I keep getting the 7.3.32 version. Also, said version wasn't listed when I executed the `update-alternatives` command